# Entity Framework - behind the scenes: DataReaders and connection life period

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, entity-framework, datareader

Another question regarding EF:

I was wondering what's going behind the scenes when iterating over a query result.

For example, check out the following code:

```
var activeSources = from e in entitiesContext.Sources
                    where e.IsActive
                    select e;
```

and then:

```
foreach (Source currSource in allSources)
{
   code based on the current source...
}
```

**Important note**: Each iteration takes a while to complete (from 1 to 25 seconds).

Now, I assume EF is based on DataReaders for maximum efficiency, so based on that assumption, I figure that in the above case, the Database connection will be kept open until I finish iterating over the results, which will be a very long time (when talking in terms of code), which is something I obviously don't want.

Is there a way to fetch the entire data like I would've done with plain old ADO.NET DataAdapters, DataSets and the fill() method instead of using DataReaders?

Or maybe i'm way off with my assumptions?

In any case I would've loved to be pointed to a good source explaining this if available.

Thanks,

Mikey

Comment: "The ToList<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>) method forces immediate query evaluation and returns a List<T> that contains the query results.You can append this method to your query in order to obtain a cached copy of the query results."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get all of the data up front, similar to `Fill()`, you need to force the query to execute.

```
var activeSources = from e in entitiesContext.Sources
                    where e.IsActive
                    select e;

var results = activeSources.ToList();
```

After `ToList()` is called you will have the data and be disconnected from the database.

Comment: Thanks, were my assumptions correct regarding DataReaders? or even close to that?

Comment: @Mikey: On that point I'm actually not sure. I remembering reading that EF uses LINQ-to-SQL under the covers, so the question would then be how is that implemented? I would also assume `DataReader`, but can't confirm. Usually @Ladislav and @Slauma have good input on those topics..

Comment: EF doesn't use Linq-to-SQL - it has completely separate implementation of data access based on ADO.NET and it really uses data readers. The assumption is correct. If you iterate through result set the reader must be kept opened.

Comment: @Ladislav: Cool, I figured you would know!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return all results at once use .ToList(); Then deferred execution won't happen.

```
var activeSources = (from e in entitiesContext.Sources
                where e.IsActive
                select e).ToList();
```

Comment: @Jethro: I think you mean *deferred execution*. Lazy loading is a different subject altogether, involving when related entities are materialized.

Comment: It is not lazy loading - it stands for different functionality. This is called deferred execution.

Comment: Oh, yeah deferred execution, mmm are they not very similar though? Almost the same?

Comment: No lazy loading and deferred execution are not the same. Deferred execution means that you define the query but the query is executed once you start iterating it or call methods like `ToList`, `First`, etc. Lazy loading means that returned entity is proxied and when you access not loaded navigation property for the first time context will trigger another query to database and load the data for you.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka, thanks, yeah I did a bit of research on that to clear it up. Thanks though.